# avoid checking for DataRow.IsDBNull on each column?

Tags: vb.net, dataset, datarow, dbnull

My code is 2x longer than it would be if I could automatically set `IsDBNull` to `""` or simply roll over it without an error.

This is my code:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection
conn.ConnectionString = Module1.DBConn2
Dim sqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", conn)
conn.Open()
Dim sqlDataset As DataSet = New DataSet()
Dim sqlDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
sqlDataAdapter.Fill(sqlDataset)
conn.Close()

For Each rs As DataRow In sqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows
    If Not IsDBNull(rs("column")) Then
        Response.Write(rs("column"))
    Else
        Response.Write("")
    End If

    Response.Write("some stuff to write")

    If Not IsDBNull(rs("column2")) Then
        Response.Write(rs("column2"))
    Else
        Response.Write("")
    End If
Next
```

In that case I'd just like to type `Response.Write(rs("column"))` instead of the `If` statement, and if `column` `IsDBNull` then output an empty string.

How can I do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx) and pass [`row.ItemArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx):

```
For Each row As DataRow In sqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows
    Response.Write(String.Join("", row.ItemArray))
Next
```

That works since [`DBNull.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkbzs85t.aspx) returns an empty string.

If you want to address every column, you can use the strongly typed [`DataRowExtensions.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field.aspx) method  which supports nullables and return `null`/`Nothing` for string. Then you could use the `null-coalescing operator` (`??` in C#, `If` in VB).

```
Dim rowInfo = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                            If(row.Field(Of String)("Column1"), ""),
                            If(row.Field(Of String)("Column2"), ""),
                            If(row.Field(Of String)("Column3"), ""))
```

However, note that `String.Format` will convert `null`/`Nothing` to `""` implicitely anyway, so the `If` is redundant and just *fyi*.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> If the object specified by index is a null reference (Nothing in
>   Visual Basic), then the format item is replaced by the empty string
>   ("").

Comment: in a word: inexperience

Comment: @gracchus: i have deleted my comment ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner:

```
Response.Write(rs.IsNull("column") ? "" : rs("column"));
```

or make it an extension  method:

```
public string GetValueOrBlankString(this DataRow rs, string column)
{
    return rs.IsNull(column) ? "" : rs(column).ToString();
}
```

then call it as:

```
Response.Write(rs.GetValueOrBlankString("column"));
```

Comment: Well the OP looks for vb.net, however using the if() function might work (but not iif as it will trow a null reference exception)

Answer (score 1):

Dataset Extensions give you a clean way of doing and it's also strongly typed. The type must match the column type in the database though. If the database column can be null, then use a nullable type like below. The null values become Nothing for the returned nullable type.

```
For Each rs As DataRow In sqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows

    'If string, you can use this. Null becomes nothing for the string.
    Response.Write(rs.field(of String)("column"))

    'if it's another type
    Response.Write(rs.field(of Integer?)("column"))


Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Ceres's answer is probably the best given that it avoids any sort of null testing, but it's worth noting that the 'IIF' function would also work pretty well her. It's still going to do the test for null but it's much more compact than how Joe was originally doing it. Something like this should do the trick:

```
For Each rs As DataRow In sqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows

    Response.Write( IIF( IsDBNull(rs("column")), "", rs("column") ) )

Next
```

What's neat with this is you can substitute the "" for whatever you want to output if the value is in fact null ( a nice little added bonus. )

Here's some info on the 'IIF' function for those who don't know what it is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: `Iif()` is part of the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace and is not a .NET function. `If()` should be used in place, and avoids an entire function call.