# Handle Null condition

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to handle `null` condition in below code.

```
    lstTest.Discount = If((Not dataSet.Tables("History") Is Nothing), 
If(IsDBNull(dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0)("DiscountsAdjustmentsAmount")),
 "$0.00", 
StringToCurrency(GetContractualDiscount(dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0)
("DiscountsAdjustmentsAmount"), dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0)
("DiscountsAdjustments"), dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0)
("EstimatedCharges")))), "$0.00")
```

My code is getting break at

```
dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0)("DiscountsAdjustments")
```

since its value is `null`. I want to replace `null value` with "0.00"

Please help how can I handle.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use multiple lines? It would increase readability, maintainability and testability enormously. It would also be easier to fix such issues.

Comment: It was coded earlier, can't change the code

Comment: I can modily it whole, it error needs to be resolved

Comment: No offense, but the code is really a complete mess. You should not abuse the conditonal operator in this way. You should also use the correct types instead of always object and string. The `DataRow` class has the `Field(Of T)` extension method that also supports nullable types. This sounds as if the column should be a `Decimal?`. Then you could get the value in this way: `Dim discountsAdjustments = dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0).Field(Of Decimal?)("DiscountsAdjustments")`

Comment: You should check if `dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0))` is null before attempting to get `dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0)("DiscountsAdjustmentsAmount")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rahul,

You will likely need to rewrite this part of it. Here is your original code:

```
   lstTest.Discount = If((Not dataSet.Tables("History") Is Nothing), 
If(IsDBNull(dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0)("DiscountsAdjustmentsAmount")),
 "$0.00", 
StringToCurrency(GetContractualDiscount(dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0)
("DiscountsAdjustmentsAmount"), dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0)
("DiscountsAdjustments"), dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0)
("EstimatedCharges")))), "$0.00")
```

Instead of this big nested mess... why not do it this way. Note I dont have a VB debugger in front of me so there may be some slight format adjustments, so consider this pseudo code:

**Is the dataset valid**

```
If Not IsDBNull(dataSet.Tables("History"))

''We know that we have data in our dataset

''Do all your checks 
if Not isDBNull(dataSet.Tables("History").Rows(0)("Your field"))
 ''Do something
Else
  ''Show a 0
END IF

''REPEAT THE ABOVE LINES FOR EACH FIELD

End if
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for null on any column first using methods on the DataRow object:

[Which of IsDBNull and IsNull should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548023/which-of-isdbnull-and-isnull-should-be-used)