# DbNull.Value and isDBNull for datacolumn

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, optimization, dbnull

I have a `DataRow` which contain data from `database`. I want to check each data column for `Null` value in an `IF` condition. 
I found two ways to check `NULL` value.

```
 If IsDBNull(drType("ISShort")) Then
    StartDate.Visible = True
 Else
    StartDate.Visible = False
 End If
```

and

```
 If Not drType("ISShort").ToString Is DBNull.Value  Then
   StartDate.Visible = True
 Else
   StartDate.Visible = False
 End If
```

Both works fine for me but I don't know which one is better to use ?

Comment: `drType("ISShort").ToString Is DBNull.Value` should give you troubles since you are converting something in a string. Is it really DBNull.Value?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly same code I used

Answer (score 3):

I prefer [`DataRow.IsNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns a `bool`, is readable and efficient:

```
StartDate.Visible = drType.IsNull("ISShort")
```

related: [Which of IsDBNull and IsNull should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548023/which-of-isdbnull-and-isnull-should-be-used)

Note that your second approach doesn't work. If you convert it to `String` with `ToString` it can't be `DBNull.Value`. That compiles only with option-strict set to `off` which i strongly advise against.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Then what is `DBNull.Value` for. The code was previously written using `DBNull.Value` and when I debug the code, it is working fine.

Comment: The last point is what I wrote in my comment. But @Abdul said he got the correct results with the ToString approach. How can that be?

Comment: The `drType("ISShort")`  contains a `boolean` value. I think, I provided a complete code section to test.

Comment: @Abdul: it works accidentially because VB tries to fix your code. It will magically convert `DbNull.Value` to a string by calling `ToString` which returns `String.Empty`. But don't do it, instead write type safe code. It wouldn't compile anyway if you'd change it to option strict on, what you should always do project-wide.

Comment: @AlexB.: look at my last comment, it's one of the "features" of VB to fix not working code for you. I wouldn't go with the [`IsDbNull` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5(v=vs.90).aspx) because it's an old "global" VB6 function, so it's not .NET and would not compile in C# and it's less efficient.

Comment: Thanks. I misread your answer as `IsDbNull` instead of `IsNull`. Those old VB6 compatibility functions are really a blessing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Second case makes no sense as it does unnecessary `ToString()`.

Note, there is another way you can use DbNull

```
If DbNull.Value.Equals(row.Item(fieldName)) Then
...
```

you can also use myDataRow.IsNull(fieldName) which is faster according to [Which of IsDBNull and IsNull should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548023/which-of-isdbnull-and-isnull-should-be-used)